# Can I call POST APIs in zap action?

Tags: github-actions

I need to know that can we call POST APIs in zap action in GitHub workflow.

I only see scanning with GET request.

The following is I tried but not working:

```yaml
      - name: OWASP ZAP Scan POST Request
        uses: zaproxy/action-api-scan@v0.5.0
        with:
          target: "$API_URL"
          zap-options: "-X POST -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d '$PAYLOAD'"
```

Comment: `zap-options` doesn't seem to be valid `input` for https://github.com/zaproxy/action-api-scan. There's this `cmd_options` but you need to first make sure that it's what you're looking for. From its [source](https://github.com/zaproxy/action-api-scan/blob/main/index.js), it doesn't look like supporting your use case.